# Searching pages exactly containing two given strings with Customsearch in Java

Tags: java, google-custom-search

I'm using `google-api-services-customsearch` v1-rev46-1.21.0 in my Java application to find the pages that contain two exact strings.

Let's say that I have two names, `Bill Gates` and `Steve Jobs`, and that I want to find all the pages that mention both of them. If I were using the Google search page, I would run the following query:

```
"Bill Gates" "Steve Jobs"
```

(notice that I haven't used the `+` sign as it's not anymore a valid operator).

I'd like to make the same exact search via Java, but I cannot find a way to make it work. Any suggestion? Please find below a **minimal working example** (`API_KEY` and `SEARCH_ENGINE_ID` have been tested and are correct):

```
public class Example {

    private static String name1 = "Bill Gates";
    private static String name2 = "Steve Jobs";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        Customsearch customsearch = new Customsearch(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
        Customsearch.Cse cse = customsearch.cse();

        String format = String.format("\"%s\" \"%s\"", name1, name2);
        Customsearch.Cse.List request = cse.list(format);
        request.setKey(Consts.API_KEY);
        request.setCx(Consts.SEARCH_ENGINE_ID);

        Search search = request.execute();
        List<Result> results = search.getItems();
        if (null != results) {
            for (Result result : results) {
                System.out.println("* " + result.getLink());
                System.out.println(result.getSnippet());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only way to get some results (that are not null) is to change the query to:

```
Bill Gates Steve Jobs
```

which means 'find any page containing one or more of the above words in any order whatsoever and it's not what I'm trying to do. Many thanks in advance for any solution or useful piece of documentation that you can provide.

---

**I just realised that the code above works perfectly with big names like `Bill Gates` and `Steve Jobs`, but it doesn't work with other names of less famous people. Does it mean that the current customsearch engine returns null when it finds no results? If so, why I get many results if I run the query on Google website?**

Answer (score 0):

The code that I posted as **minimal working example** is correct.
The reason why I was getting no results is that I put to many restrictions to the Customsearch engine in the Google's control panel (i.e.: no results from LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter, etc.). When I relaxed the constraint, I got the desired results.